# Lifespan of steel frame houses

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, civil-engineering

We are considering to build our family house. Where I live, people build either:

1. Concrete beams for the structure and then thermal bricks for the external walls; or,
2. Heavy duty steel structure and then some drywall system for the exterior.

In both cases, there is a concrete slab at the base.

I love the look of the steel structures, their design, speed to construction, insulation capabilities, etc. However, I am wondering about their lifespan. For concrete and brick houses, it is not uncommon to have a house renovated at 50 years and look like new.

- What is the lifespan of residential houses built with steel structure?
- Can I expect to grow old in the house and that my children will inherit it, or should I consider that in 50 years they would have to demolish it and rebuild?

Comment: Where you are building can influence the decision.

Comment: There are many very old houses made of wood... There are newer houses made of concrete that need demolishing... Good design makes a difference along with common sense and understanding of the enviroment.

Comment: @EricS Mediterranean. Meaning mild winters (5-10 degrees Celsius) and hot summers (30-35 degrees). Lots of humidity but not close to the sea.

Comment: This is not my field. Certain construction methods work well in certain locals. Places with seismic activity tend to not have masonry construction for example. Desert places often have thick walls such as adobe in the southwest US because it absorbs daytime heat and reradiates at night. I'm assuming housing in the Mediterranean have accommodations to local environmental conditions. I'm sure steel construction can be long lived, but finding an architect and builder experienced with a material is important.